# Get record count of each table?

Tags: sql-server, row, dbvisualizer

I have 700 tables, and I want to know the record count of each table using dbvisualizer.

How can do simply and effective? Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{database}';`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  distinct t.name, p.rows
FROM    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
        ON t.object_id = p.object_id
ORDER BY t.name
```